# java - Cant change the value of a JTextfield from inside of DocumentListener methods

Tags: java, swing, textfield

I get an "Attempt to mutate in notification" exception.
1. How can I change it ? 
2. How can I get the value that was inside the TextField before the listener was triggered?

EDIT:

It is something like this. On the JTextfield I have this listener

```
basePriceTF.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){ 
     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){ 
        if (Integer.getValue(basePriceTF.getText())<0){
        basePriceTF.setText("0");
        }
     }

     public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){/**my implemntation**/}

     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){/**my implemntation**/}
}

insertUpdate() will probably cause a loop.
So it doesnt let me change inside basePriceTF.
```

Comment: Maybe some code would be helpful. Can you please provide it in an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) format?

Answer (score 4):

As was pointed out three times so far,
this is exactly what `DocumentFilter`s are made for.
Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that does what you want:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;

public class TestDocumentFilter extends JFrame {
  JTextField basePriceTF;

public TestDocumentFilter() {
    super("TestDocumentFilter");
    basePriceTF = new JTextField();
    AbstractDocument basePriceDocument = (AbstractDocument) basePriceTF.getDocument();
    basePriceDocument.setDocumentFilter(new PositiveIntegerFilter());
    getContentPane().add(basePriceTF);
}

/**
 * Resets the document to "0" for input values that do not constitut a non-negative integer.
 */
private static class PositiveIntegerFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String inputTextValue,
            AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        Document oldDoc = fb.getDocument();
        String textValue = oldDoc.getText(0, oldDoc.getLength()) + inputTextValue;
        Integer basePrice = 0;
        try {
            basePrice = Integer.parseInt(textValue);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
            basePrice = 0;
        }
        if (basePrice < 0) 
            basePrice = 0;
        fb.replace(0, oldDoc.getLength(), basePrice.toString(), attrs);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new TestDocumentFilter();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

You cannot enter "-1"; the field is reset to "0" when "-" is typed.  Note the `FilterBypass` which avoids any recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

Per the DocumentListener tutorial and API, DocumentListeners should not modify the contents of the Document, so the short answer is: don't do this.

Consider using something else perhaps a DocumentFilter or some other validating method.

Comment: I usually do it differently . I have another thread in the GUI that refreshes the GUI from its module. but then : A. It is too much code(as usual with gui). B. upon refreshing (all the components are refreshed) every component enters its listener to check validity. if the refresh is every half a sec - this is too much work IMO. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: @user450602: *again* you could use a DocumentFilter.

Comment: +1, @user450602 - since you expect this field to contain integer values, you should be using the DocumentFilter to make sure that only numeric character are ever entered into the text field anyway. Now you just add a second check. If "-" is entered, then you replace all the existing text with "0".

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a good practice, but it should work, and it doesn't involve any complicated nor any expensive stuff.

```
final Document doc = basePriceTF.getDocument();
basePriceTF.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        if (Integer.getValue(basePriceTF.getText())<0){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    doc.removeDocumentListener(this);
                    basePriceTF.setText("0");        
                    doc.addDocumentListener(this);
                }
            }).start();
        }     
     }
     .......
```

You can also use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() if you are afraid to execute the code at the wrong moment. It should also work.

Comment: Somewhere... someplace.. I thought about this solution too. Let's just  say this would be my last resort... But thanks anyways.