# Java - Observer Pattern in regards to some code. Mimic syncronized text update

Tags: java, design-patterns, document, observer-pattern, jtextarea

The purpose of my code is to mimic the functionality of Google Docs - when a user types on one machine, the letters they type appear on another machine. For simplistic purposes, each machine types text in a gui, and a main class handles all changes.

[image]
Every machine has an "Editor" and is linked up to a total of 1 "File Content Subject". The "File Content Subject" is supposed to make the changes a user makes and send the updated code to all "Editors"

[image]

This begins with a simple **driver** where I make a File Content Subject, create two Editors and connect these together

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileContentSubject filecontentsubject = new FileContentSubject();
    
    Editor e1 = new Editor(filecontentsubject);
    Editor e2 = new Editor(filecontentsubject);
    
    filecontentsubject.attach(e1);
    filecontentsubject.attach(e2);  
}
}
```

The **Editor** looks like this (the two pop up windows, not the rest):
[image]

The code that makes the Editor is here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;


public class Editor extends JFrame implements DocumentListener, Observer {

private FileContentSubject reference;
private Document doc;

    private JScrollPane textAreaScrollPane;
    private JTextArea textArea;
      
 
public Editor(FileContentSubject filecontentsubject) {
    super("Editor");
    initComponents();
    
    this.reference = filecontentsubject;
    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(reference);
     
}
 
 
private void initComponents(){
    
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setColumns(5);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setRows(50);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
     
    textAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    
    
    setLocation(600,100);
    setSize(500,400);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
}


@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
}


@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {      
    reference.insertUpdate(arg0);
}


@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    reference.removeUpdate(arg0);
}


@Override
public void update() {
    //textArea.setText(reference.getJTextArea());
    //textArea.setText(reference.temp);
    
}   
}
```

The only **Problem** right now with my code is within the **File Content Subject**, when I try to change the code that I get passed by through the Editor. I am getting many "cannot mutate within notification" and somethings a "null pointer exception" error. The code that generates this is below and is the part I have **commented out.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.Position;


public class FileContentSubject implements Subject, DocumentListener {

private JTextArea textArea;
private Document doc;

private SubjectImpl reference;


@Override
public void attach(Observer o) {
    reference.attach(o);
}

@Override
public void detach(Observer o) {
    reference.detach(o);
}

@Override
public void notifyAllObservers() {
    reference.notifyAllObservers();
}


public FileContentSubject(){
    reference = new SubjectImpl();
    
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setTabSize(5);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    doc = (Document)arg0.getDocument();

    
//      try {
//          //this.textArea.setText(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()-1));
//      } catch (BadLocationException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
    notifyAllObservers();
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    doc = (Document)arg0.getDocument();
    
//      try {
//          this.textArea.setText(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()-1));
//      } catch (BadLocationException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }       
    
    notifyAllObservers();
}





public String getJTextArea(){
    return textArea.getText();
}
}
```

So my question is, how can I pass text in (by passing in a DocumentEvent through an Editor) into the File Content Subject, have it change the File Content Subject, and notify all Editors?

---

My other classes that make this all happen (not important but shown for clarity):

**Subject Interface**

```
/**
 * Interface
 */
public interface Subject {

public void attach(Observer o);
public void detach(Observer o);

public void notifyAllObservers();

}
```

**Observer Interface**

```
public interface Observer {

    public void update();
}
```

**SubjectImpl class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SubjectImpl implements Subject {

private List <Observer> observers;

public SubjectImpl(){
    observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
}


@Override
public void attach(Observer o) {
    observers.add(o);
}

@Override
public void detach(Observer o) {
    observers.remove(o);
}

@Override
public void notifyAllObservers() {
    for(Observer o: observers){
        o.update();
    }
}
}
```

---

---

---

## **ANSWER**

Needed to prevent the Editor that was editing itself from being updated. This was done with document properties and maintaining everything in a string rather than JTextArea. BIG thanks to acdcjunior for helping out and code answer are on the very last three code blocks in selected answer.

Comment: Yes I turn system settings to low so my computer can run/render faster

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a class name the same as a JDK class, in your case `Observer` is also in `java.util` package

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, as its a simple problem I will not change it but I will remember this for the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification` is thrown because in these lines in `FileContentSubject`:

```
@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    doc = (Document) arg0.getDocument();

    try {
        this.textArea.setText(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()-1));
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyAllObservers();
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    doc = (Document) arg0.getDocument();

    try {
        this.textArea.setText(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()-1));
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    notifyAllObservers();
}
```

And this line at `FileContentSubject`'s constructor:

```
textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
```

**show that you are trying to change the value of the `textArea` from inside the `DocumentListener` methods.**

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088069/java-cant-change-the-value-of-a-jtextfield-from-inside-of-documentlistener-met), **you should use a `DocumentFilter` for that purpose**.

Here's a simple working example of `DocumentFilter`'s use (it replaces all typed chars with their uppercase version):

```
//UpcaseFilter.java
//A simple DocumentFilter that maps lowercase letters to uppercase.

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class UpcaseFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
            String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        fb.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
    }

    // no need to override remove(): inherited version allows all removals
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
            String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentFilter dfilter = new UpcaseFilter();

        JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
        ((AbstractDocument) jta.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(dfilter);
        ((AbstractDocument) jtf.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(dfilter);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("UpcaseFilter");
        frame.getContentPane().add(jta, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jtf, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 120);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

(The above example was taken from the [Java Swing, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004088.do) book, [chapter 22](http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/ch22/UpcaseFilter.java).)

### That's the reason for the exception thrown, but you'll have to do more to correct you code:

In short, the problem is that this happens in your code:

- When an `Editor` instance's (let's call it `edt`) `textArea` changes...
- ...the `FileContentSubject` (as it is a `DocumentListener`) notices the event and then notifies all its registered observers (`edt` included!) to call their `update()` method...
- ...the `update()` method of `edt` changes its `textArea` and... voilá! You are trying to change the `textArea` who started the event (before the event ends)!

All you have to do then is find a way of not notifying who started the event. The code below uses `Document.putProperty()` and  `Document.getProperty()` for that: it detaches the event's source editor (`reference.detach(e);`), notifies everyone of the change, and reattaches it (`reference.attach(e);`).

(Also, I replaced `FileContentSubject`'s `JTextArea` with a `String`, as just that `String` will suffice.)

So, heres the changed `FileContentSubject` code:

```
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class FileContentSubject implements Subject, DocumentListener {

    // private JTextArea textArea; // removed as a String field will suffice
    // private Document doc; // should not be a field!

    private String state;

    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    private SubjectImpl reference;

    @Override
    public void attach(Observer o) {
        reference.attach(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void detach(Observer o) {
        reference.detach(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyAllObservers() {
        reference.notifyAllObservers();
    }

    public FileContentSubject() {
        reference = new SubjectImpl();

//      textArea = new JTextArea();
//      textArea.setTabSize(5);
//      textArea.setLineWrap(true);
//      textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
//      textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        Document doc = (Document) arg0.getDocument();
        try {
            // this.textArea.setText(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()-1));
            this.state = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Editor e = (Editor) doc.getProperty("ownerEditor");
        reference.detach(e); // so it will not be notified of its own change
        notifyAllObservers(); // tell everybody else to catch up with the changes
        reference.attach(e); // reattaches the editor
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        Document doc = (Document) arg0.getDocument();
        try {
            // this.textArea.setText(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()-1));
            this.state = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Editor e = (Editor) doc.getProperty("ownerEditor");
        reference.detach(e); // so it will not be notified of its own change
        notifyAllObservers(); // tell everybody else to catch up with the changes
        reference.attach(e); // reattaches the editor
    }

    // public String getJTextArea() {
    //     return textArea.getText();
    // }
}
```

The changed `Editor`'s constructor:

```
public Editor(FileContentSubject filecontentsubject) {
    super("Editor");
    initComponents();

    this.reference = filecontentsubject;
    textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(reference);
    textArea.getDocument().putProperty("ownerEditor", this); // <---- ADDED LINE
}
```

and `update()`:

```
@Override
public void update() {
    //textArea.setText(reference.getJTextArea());
    //textArea.setText(reference.temp);
    textArea.setText(reference.getState()); // ADDED
}
```

That's it!

Comment: I think by placing this in my File Content Subject, and giving a reference of this to each Editor, I am able to synchronize the code. Thanks for your time to type this out, I will try and implement what you suggest.

Comment: @JimRilye I'm not sure I understand what you just said, but, I added a section of further corrections in your code. Check it out. Let me know if I can help you in any way.

Comment: DocumentFilter is an interface? I am not finding one, it is a class, must I extend?

Comment: Edit: extended DocumentFilter to File Content Subject and now "finding" a way to add this to the JTextArea in Editor

Comment: @JimRilye Of course, you are correct, `DocumentFilter` is a class and you must extend it (the example shows this behavior). I had `DocumentListener` in mind when wrote the answer. Edited it now.

Comment: File Content Subject now extends Document Filter. It has the methods overriden, only to print characters to the screen (to make sure it is working). The Editor class now has an AbstractDocument private member, and I assign the File Content Subject as the Editor's textArea's document filter as such: doc = (AbstractDocument)textArea.getDocument();  doc.setDocumentFilter(reference); ---- Additonally, all of the DocumentListener methods in Editor (because it implements it) are empty too. I have put print statements in these overridden methods and none of them even show.

Comment: You have to make FileContenSubject update all observers textAreas. I'm getting a bit confused. I'm gonna edit your code and post it.

Comment: @JimRilye there you go, I pretty much rewrote all the answer. I did it in a way you'll have to do minimal changes to your code (you'll not need to use `DocumentFilter` for example). Read it and tell me if it works for you!

Comment: The property was needed so we could pull that Editor out and not notify it? That was very clever acdcjunior! I have to thank you this works wonderfully, thank you again for explaining a lot. You helped me understand what needs to be done here. Have a nice night!